# Favicon works well when loading from remote while doesn't work for local file, how do I fix it?

Tags: html, favicon

I'm trying to add a Favicon to my Site.

This code works as expected

```
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvjfT.png" sizes="16x16"/>
        <title>home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>favicon png</h1>
    </body>
```

and I got this

[image]

However, when I change the value of href

```
href="favicon.png"
```

my site doesn't load it any more.

[image]

my index.html and favicon.png are at the same directory.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the network tab from dev tools. Does it load the correct file?

Comment: Try an incognito mode in your browser or another browser. Sometime a browser caches icon and displays an old one. But first double check you console - there might be some error message.

Comment: @cloned No, it doesn't load the file at all

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky I've tried the incognito mode but it still cannot load the favicon and no error.

Comment: The `link` code looks okay. So I have no more guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Open the source code of the "index.html" file in a tab and open the favicon.png from the code by clicking on it, and in another side open the favicon.png in another tab from the directory. And now compare both the URL, you will find difference.